# Number system converter

Tags: c, math

This should be a program that converts a number contained in a string, `str` from base `m` to decimal. The problem is that, on the final iteration of the `for` loop, it takes the entire number as a digit instead of taking only the leftmost digit in the string.

For example: if `str` equals "100", then on the last iteration, instead of taking digit 1, it takes 100.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int m = 0;
    char str[100];
    
    scanf("%d\n%s", &m, str);

    int length = strlen(str);

    int number = 0;
    int power = 0;

    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        int digit = 0;
        if (isalpha(str[i])){
            switch(str[i]){
                case 'A': digit = 10;break;
                case 'B': digit = 11;break;
                case 'C': digit = 12;break;
                case 'D': digit = 13;break;
                case 'E': digit = 14;break;
                case 'F': digit = 15;
            }
        }
        else{
            sscanf(&str[i], "%d", &digit);
        }
        
        number += digit*pow((double)m, (double)power);
        power++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `strtol()` ?

Comment: With `sscanf(&str[i], "%d", &digit);`, scanning is not limited to 1 character.  Scanning does _start_ at `&str[i]` but may end many chracters later.  The simple atlernative here is  `digit = str[i] - '0';` if `str[i]` is a digit.